# Can I serve a Vue/TS app from a wwwroot folder in a .Net Framework 4.5.2 WebAPI appl?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vuejs2, .net-4.5

I have a 4.5.2 WebAPI that is accessed from a Vuejs2/TypeScript SPA app.

I want to overcome CORS by running the built Vue2 app from a subfolder directly in the WebAPI app (e.g. wwwroot or clientapp).

Is this possible on WebAPI 4.5.2?

How do I wire up the pages in this old app?